# Is it possible to limit macbook display resolution/size for part of the screen?

Tags: macos, display, screen, resolution

My Macbook after falling incident lost it's 3 centimetres of screen on right hand side (the rest of the screen still works) - is it possible to change resolution (and limit width) and not use that part of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend using SwitchResX to find a resolution that works for you:

https://www.madrau.com/

Note that you will have to live with the fact that the displayed area is in the center of the display, thus if you want to "block" a part of the right hand side of the display, you'll also have to block a part of the left hand side of the display of the same size.